# database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked+Null PointerExpception Error Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout

I am working on android application that need to get data from table using sqlite and show the specific items in the list view. As I try to run the application the application got error getDatabaseLocked and show error on sqlite database...

here is my sqlite file..

```
{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
Context context;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DynamicERP.db";

public static final String table_orders = "TABLEORDERS";
public static final String table_poducts_records = "PRODUCTSRECORDS";


public static final String code = "ORDERCODE";
public static final String barcode = "BARCODE";
public static final String nametblp = "NAME";
public static final String size = "SIZE";
public static final String uname = "UNAME";
public static final String retail = "RETAIL";
public static final String wholesale = "WHOLESALE";
public static final String trade = "TRADE";
public static final String percentage = "PERCENTAGE";
public static final String tax = "TAX";
public static final String subcatagary = "SUBCATAGARY";
public static final String categary = "CATEGARY";
public static final String company = "COMPANY";
public static final String type = "TYPE";
public static final String packsize = "PACKSIZE";
public static final String weight = "WEIGHT";
public static final String weightunit = "WEIGHTUNIT";
public static final String currentstock = "CURRENTSTOCK";


public static final String salecode = "SALECODE";
public static final String mcode = "MCODE";
public static final String fname = "FIRSTNAME";
public static final String lname = "LASTNAME";
public static final String urduname = "URDUNAME";
public static final String address = "ADDRESS";
public static final String contact = "CONTACT";
public static final String cnic = "CNIC";
public static final String saletype = "TYPE";
public static final String route = "ROUTE";
public static final String area = "AREA";
public static final String zone = "ZONE";
public static final String balance = "BALANCE";
public static final String creditlimit = "CREDITLIMIT";
public static final String spl = "SPL";
public static final String saletax = "SALETAX";

private static final String DATABASE_ORDERS = "CREATE TABLE " + table_orders + "("
        + code + " INTEGER, " + barcode + " VARCHAR," + nametblp + " VARCHAR," + size + " VARCHAR," + uname +
        " VARCHAR," + retail + " VARCHAR," + wholesale + " VARCHAR," + trade + " VARCHAR,"
        + percentage + " VARCHAR," + tax + " VARCHAR," + subcatagary + " VARCHAR," + categary + " VARCHAR," +
        company + " VARCHAR," + type + " VARCHAR," + packsize + " VARCHAR," +
        weight + " VARCHAR," + weightunit + " VARCHAR, " + currentstock + " VARCHAR );";


private static final String DATABASE_PRODUCTS = "CREATE TABLE " + table_poducts_records + "("
        + salecode + " INTEGER, " + mcode + " VARCHAR, " + fname + " VARCHAR, " + lname + " VARCHAR, " + urduname +
        " VARCHAR, " + address + " NVARCHAR, " + contact + " VARCHAR," + cnic + " VARCHAR, " + saletype + " VARCHAR,"
        + route + " VARCHAR, " + area + " VARCHAR," + zone + " VARCHAR," +
        balance + " VARCHAR, " + creditlimit + " VARCHAR," + spl + " VARCHAR, " + saletax + " VARCHAR);";

private String DROP_ORDER_REC = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_orders;
private String DROP_PRODUCTS_REC = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_poducts_records;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_ORDERS);
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_PRODUCTS);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_PRODUCTS_REC);
    db.execSQL(DROP_ORDER_REC);
    onCreate(db);
}


public List<GetSetOrders> getAllOrderData() {

    String[] columns = {
            nametblp,
            code,
            retail,
            subcatagary,
            company
    };


    String sortOrder = code + " ASC";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    db.isOpen();

    List<GetSetOrders> clientlist = new ArrayList<GetSetOrders>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(table_poducts_records, //Table to query
            columns,    //columns to return
            null,        //columns for the WHERE clause
            null,        //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,       //group the rows
            null,       //filter by row groups
            sortOrder); //The sort order

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            GetSetOrders orders = new GetSetOrders();

            orders.setNAME(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(nametblp)));
            orders.setORDERCODE(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(code)));
            orders.setRETAIL(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(retail)));
            orders.setCATEGARY(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(subcatagary)));
            orders.setCOMPANY(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(company)));
            clientlist.add(orders);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return clientlist;
}
```

Here is my crash log which shows the error of the database close

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
    at com.example.tablewithlist.DatabaseHelper.getAllOrderData(DatabaseHelper.java:182)
    at com.example.tablewithlist.Clients$2.doInBackground(Clients.java:67)
    at com.example.tablewithlist.Clients$2.doInBackground(Clients.java:63)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
```

Here is my Adapter Class

```
{

private List<GetSetOrders> listOrders;
Context mContext;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
View itemView;

public ClientRecyclerAdapter(List<GetSetOrders> listOrders, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.listOrders =  listOrders;
    mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
}

@Override
public ClientViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    mContext = parent.getContext();
    itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.items_products_table, parent, false);

    return new ClientViewHolder(itemView);
}


public class ClientViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //public AppCompatTextView ID;
    public TextView lblPName;
    public TextView lblTrade;
    public TextView lblRetail;
    public TextView lblSubCategary;
    public TextView lblCompany;
    RelativeLayout layout;

    public ClientViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);


        lblPName =  view.findViewById(R.id.lblPName);
        lblTrade =  view.findViewById(R.id.lblTrade);
        lblRetail =  view.findViewById(R.id.lblRetail);
        lblSubCategary = view.findViewById(R.id.lblSubCategary);
        lblCompany =  view.findViewById(R.id.lblCompany);
        layout = view.findViewById(R.id.listprod);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ClientViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.lblPName.setText(listOrders.get(position).getNAME());
    holder.lblTrade.setText(listOrders.get(position).getORDERCODE());
    holder.lblRetail.setText(listOrders.get(position).getRETAIL());
    holder.lblSubCategary.setText(listOrders.get(position).getSUBCATAGARY());
    holder.lblCompany.setText(listOrders.get(position).getCOMPANY());
    holder.layout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.v(ClientRecyclerAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), "" + listOrders.size());
    return listOrders.size();

}
```

}

This is the main class where I am calling the function of the database...

```
{

Activity activity;
RecyclerView recyclerViewClients;
Button btnAll;
ClientRecyclerAdapter clientRecyclerAdapter;
List<GetSetOrders> listclients;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.clients, container, false);

    btnAll=view.findViewById(R.id.searchall);
    recyclerViewClients=view.findViewById(R.id.Viewclients);

    listclients = new ArrayList<>();
    clientRecyclerAdapter = new ClientRecyclerAdapter(listclients,recyclerViewClients);
    recyclerViewClients.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerViewClients.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerViewClients.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewClients.setAdapter(clientRecyclerAdapter);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);


    btnAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getClientFromSqlite();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Usman", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void getClientFromSqlite() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            listclients.clear();
            listclients.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllOrderData());
           // clientRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            clientRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

}

Here is my Fragment activity which contain Viewpager class client..

```
 {
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_fragment);

    databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Dynamic ERPMini");

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Clients"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Products"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Invoices"));

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagersAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

The New Error Crash Log by updating the code..

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: NAME (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT NAME, ORDERCODE, RETAIL, SUBCATAGARY, COMPANY FROM PRODUCTSRECORDS ORDER BY ORDERCODE ASC
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
    at com.example.tablewithlist.DatabaseHelper.getAllOrderData(DatabaseHelper.java:175)
    at com.example.tablewithlist.Clients$2.doInBackground(Clients.java:65)
    at com.example.tablewithlist.Clients$2.doInBackground(Clients.java:61)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
```

Comment: Upload your full database helper code, then only able to find solution.

Comment: working on Itb to upload

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the context received by DataBaseHelper constructor. May be it has NULL value.

Try this,

```
databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
```

For Second issue, You need to revisit to your table structure or query construction. Error log said there is no column named as "NAME" in table which is your querying table. Please check once again the basics.

Comment: How to git rid of this issue

Comment: Put breakpoint in constructor check the value in context. If it is null you need to where you call this database helper otherwise try approach in other way.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer a little bit

Comment: I mean, You wrongly sent the context. You pass NULL value to DataBaseHelper. Please update your questions with where you call the DataBaseHelper that is Activity code in which you call this. This will help me update my answer or check whether my thought is correct.

Comment: I have edited the question with the classes related to db helper class

Comment: Your main class is activity or adapter class, we are near the answer

Comment: It is the class which is related to the fragment activity and that fragment contain 3 classes

Comment: these classes are Viewpager and their main is the framgment activity

Comment: where to put this line; whether in db class or main clientclass?

Comment: by adding this line in client class, the error moved to next line in db helper class and the next line is..

Comment: Cursor cursor = db.query(table_poducts_records, 
                columns,    
                null,      
                null,       
                null,       
                null,    
                sortOrder);

Comment: I am updating my question with new crash log... and the error is under the line Cursor cursor = db.query(table_poducts_records,
                columns,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder);

Comment: The error is gone but the data I want to show is not showing in list